# CATransformLayer doesn't support implicit animation?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, calayer, catransformlayer

Here's my animation code:

```
CGFloat zDistance = 850;
CGFloat scaleFactor = BACK_COVER_WIDTH / self.transformLayer.bounds.size.width;
CATransform3D rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
CATransform3D scale = CATransform3DMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 0.0);
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DConcat(rotation, scale);
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -zDistance;
CGPoint location = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.layer.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.layer.frame));
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:1.0];
self.transformLayer.transform = transform;
self.transformLayer.position = location;
[CATransaction commit];
```

`self.transformLayer` is a `CATransformLayer` with two sublayers, one for the front and one for the back (I'm creating a "flip" effect). However, this code just sets the position and transform without animation. So I thought that maybe `transform` doesn't support implicit animation, so I took that out and just tried setting the position, but that didn't animate either (and I know for sure that `position` supports implicit animation).

Am I doing something wrong or does `CATransformLayer` just not support implicit animation? The documentation does not say anything about it not supporting it, so I'm assuming it does.

**EDIT: This is for Mac OS X, not iOS**

Comment: Have you tried using an explicit animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using explicit animation, but David Duncan's answer [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/298560-catransformlayer-doesn-support-implicit-animation.html) seems like a step in the right direction for anyone else who comes across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit animations are disabled for all layers associated with `UIView`s. I have a much more [detailed response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749343/when-exactly-do-implicit-animations-take-place-in-ios/4751531#4751531) on another question if you're curious as to the details. But in short, if you want animations on a layer associated with a view, you need to do them explicitly (i.e. attach `CAAnimation` objects using `-addAnimation:forKey:`).

**Edit**: It turns out this question is for OS X, and the CATransformLayer is actually a sublayer anyway. Please disregard this answer (though the linked answer is still useful for iOS).

Comment: This isn't for iOS, its for Mac OS X. I should have made that more clear in my post. The transform layer is a sublayer of the view's layer (the view being a layer hosting view).

Comment: Ah hah. In that case, I don't know. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Only the sublayers of a `CATransformLayer` are rendered. So my guess is that its `transform` property is never applied. Have you tried setting the `sublayerTransform` property instead? It seems like that's what you're going for anyway.

Comment: According to the question, his code does set the transform, it simply doesn't animate.

Comment: Oops. I missed that somehow. Maybe `CATransformLayer` doesn't support animating any of its properties?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a layer and try to animate it in the same run loop, the animation won't happen - it'll occur instantly. You need to wrap adding the layer in a CATransaction. Afterwards, you can either implicitly or explicitly animate. For example, this should work:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:transformLayer];
[CATransaction commit];

// implicit animation will now occur because we're in the next run loop
transformLayer.transform = newTransform;
```