# How can I enable implicit UIView animation?

Tags: ios, animation, ios5, core-animation

Trying to wrap my brain around animations here. Here is my basic situation:

```
 _________
|Parent   |
|         |
|         |
|  _____  |  _____
| |A    | | |B    |
| |_____| | |_____|
|_________|
```

where `Parent` is the parent view and `A` and `B` are both `UIView` instances. I chose to make `A` and `B` `UIView`s because, as I understand it, layers cannot receive user interaction. The animation I want to do is very simple: I simply want `A` to slide offscreen to the left while `B` slides in from the right.

I tried something like the following:

```
CALayer *layer = viewA.layer;
layer.position = CGPointMake(initialLayer.position.x, initialLayer.position.y - 480);
```

but the property updated immediately with no animation.

I was able to get this working using `CABasicAnimation` without too much trouble, but I want to learn to use implicit animations for this kind of scenario so I can prototype more quickly in the future. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4749343/777929) seems to suggest that `UIView`s can't perform implicit animation (at least by default).

My question:

1. Is there a way to implicitly animate properties on a `UIView`'s layer? How?
2. If not, is there a better/canonical way to do this that's different from my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `animateWithDuration`:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    viewA.frame = newFrame;
}];
```