# What is the canonical way to animate views over a fixed background?

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard

In my two recent questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9753993/777929) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9781056/777929) I laid out my problem a bit, but I want to ask a more general question here. First my goal: I am trying to animate views side to side with a fixed background image.

I am new to iOS, and so I don't know all the tools that are available to me, but each time I started hacking this together I kept thinking that there must be a built-in way to do this. I didn't want to reinvent the wheel, so what is the common way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach I think is making a UIView based in two main views:

- The background, that always will stay
- And on top of it, another UIView with your animated view

In case you want to animate it, its quite easy, just check this:

[iPhone UIView Animation Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630265/iphone-uiview-animation-best-practice)

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer! I guess I was making things too complicated.