# How do I use implicit animation to animate a layer when the app first loads?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have the following code to animate a layer in viewDidLoad in my view controller. Basically, I want the animation to show when the view is loaded.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIView* mainview = self.view;
    CompassLayer* cl = [CompassLayer new];
    cl.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 200, 200);
    [cl assembleSublayers];
    [mainview.layer addSublayer:cl];

    CAMediaTimingFunction* clunk = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:.9 :.1 :.7 :.9];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    [CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:clunk];
    cl.arrow.transform = CATransform3DRotate(cl.arrow.transform, M_PI/4.0, 0, 0, 1);

//    CATransition* t = [CATransition animation];
//    t.type = kCATransitionPush;
//    t.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
//    [cl addAnimation:t forKey:nil];

}
```

The commented out transition animation works, but not the layer transform ones above. Can someone explain to me why?

Basically, the layer that I am trying to animate comes out in its final state.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what `viewDidLoad` is for.  This method is for doing additional setup after the ViewController loads the view hierarchy.  The view is not going to be visible on the screen when `viewDidLoad` is called so you're not going to see the animation.

Try moving your code to `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The animation still did not appear even when I've moved it to viewDidAppear. Do you know if there is anything wrong with the animation code?

Comment: Yeah.  It looks like the rest of the answer is in jrturton's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, implicit animations are disabled on iOS unless you are within a UIView animation block - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749343/when-exactly-do-implicit-animations-take-place-in-ios/4751531#475153) for more discussion.

You need to explicitly begin and commit a CATransaction to see this animation.

I agree with the other answer that it shouldn't be in viewDidLoad - you've got no guarantee the view has been added to your window at that point, viewDidAppear is a better place.