# touchesBegan with delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, gesture, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a subclass of `UIView`, and added the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnd` methods...

In `touchesBegan`, I set the `backgroundColor` from white to green by using `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]` ... in the `touchesEnd` I reset the color to white.

It works but very slowly. By tapping the view, it takes 0.5 - 1.0 sec until I see the green color.

Selecting a cell in a `UITableView` it's much faster.

Comment: hm, might be due to an implicit animation when setting properties like backGroudn color. Can you check if the touch is late or only the change of color?

Comment: This UIView of yours happens to be inside of a UITableView or a UIScrollView ?

Comment: @Volker Nice thinking, but `UIKit` disables implicit animations of underlying `CALayer`s ([see this great answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749343/when-exactly-do-implicit-animations-take-place-in-ios)), so I guess this is not the problem. I would look for `delaysContentTouches` of a superview or something similar.

Comment: @Thedude -> yes, its a UITableViewCell

Comment: I know this has already an accepted answer, but I suggest you try this out: UITableViews delay content touches by default. It has a property called delaysContentTouches, you should set it to NO. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/delaysContentTouches

Comment: delayContentTouches = NO -> same delay :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doCallMethod:)];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    recognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.0;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

- (void)doCallMethod:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        NSLog(@"Begin");
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        NSLog(@"End");
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

**Note:**
It will work more faster.

Comment: ok this works but if i putmy new View in a UITableViewCell ... i'cant swipe the cell to see the remove button :-(

Comment: Works, but if the view is inside a superView of kind UIScrollView... the ScrollView can't scroll by beginning the scroll inside the view with minimumDressDuration = 0.0  ... so you have to adjust this value to e.g. 0.1 ... and the UIScrollView is able to scroll

Comment: why touchesBegan will have delay? anyway to speed up?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a gesture recognizer as TheBurgerShot suggested but I recommend you an `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. Something like:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeColor:)];
gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.f;
[self.yourView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

in your `viewDidLoad`. And:

```
-(void) changeColor:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        self.yourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        self.yourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know why touchesbegan has some delay? use gesture can solve the trouble but can't have every attributes like touchesbegan like multiple touch.